# How to use copyout in kernel?

Tags: c, operating-system, bsd

In the kernel space I want to copy a character from the terminal and put it in a user space.

I am trying this code, but it's not working:

```
char mychar;
int result;
mychar = getch();
result = copyout(&mychar, chptr, sizeof(mychr));
```

(`chptr` is a pointer to the user level space)

`copyout` is not returning 1. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Are you sure you meant to tag this "linux" ? As far as I know `linux` doesn't have the `copyout` function (sounds more like BSD). Which OS are you using ?

Comment: you are correct, i didn't mean that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a BSD-ish `copyout`:

```
RETURN VALUES
     The copy functions return 0 on success or EFAULT if a bad address is
      encountered. ...
```

In other words, you're just expecting something other than what it returns. :-)